# Javascript validation code for hostnames with a predefined domain name

Tags: javascript, whmcs

I have an order form where the user is asked to enter his server hostname for example. Since I'm using WHMCS and pretty much all the php code is encrypted with IonCube loaders, I'm trying to find a way to add a custom validation check as follows:

The user can enter any hostname he likes like user1.abc.com etc.
I want to be able that, no matter what the user enters in the server hostname field, the final result to be user1.domain.com where domain.com is the domain I'm using since as soon as the container/vm is created, a DNS entry is automatically created.

Is it possible to add such a check using javascript? I must say that WHCMS uses .tpl template files for the order form.

What I came up with is a regex like this:

```
/^[a-z\d]([a-z\d\-]{0,61}[a-z\d])?(\.[a-z\d]([a-z\d\-]{0,61}[a-z\d])?)*$/i
```

The problem is that the regex above does a general hostname validation which is good, but I specifically need it for domain.com.

To be more specific, if the user enters user1.abc.com, the form should automatically corrected and user1.abc.com changes into user1.domain.com

Comment: What happens if the user enters `user1.abc.co.uk`? Or something like `user1.user2.abc.com` what should the result be?

Comment: What I want is that, no matter what the user wants, the final hostname will look like user1.domain.com where domain.com should always be the same no matter what...

Comment: @BogdanStoica, ok that's fine, but how do you know what is name of user and where he typed his domain? Do you have restriction for dots in username? Or maybe some other rules?

Comment: There aren't any at this point and the form asks to enter your hostname which should be in the format host.domain.tld. The issue here is that, the users, even if it's mentioned that the hostname should be in that format and the mandatory domain for that is domain.com, they usually enter stuff like user1 or user1.abc.com  and not user1.domain.com and so on. Since I can't edit any php files because all the code is encrypted, I'll have to find another way (and I do not have admin rights on that whmcs) but I do have access to all the files via FTP

Comment: In the end I've managed to do it way simpler than I've expected by adding a pattern attribute to the input field inside the form:                                          `<input type="text" name="hostname" class="form-control" id="inputHostname" value="{$server.hostname}" placeholder="servername.domain.com" pattern=".+domain.com" autofocus required />`. That does an automatic validation and if anything else is entered than user1.domain.com it throws a message to insert the proper hostname

Answer (score 0):

You can just add domain as a word, like this:

```
/^[a-z\d]([a-z\d\-]{0,61}[a-z\d])?(\.\b(domain.com)\b)/
```

[For testing](https://regex101.com/r/1PyZ1L/1)

Comment: I think what the OP wants is to exchange the `abc.com` part for `domain.com`

Comment: @Luca, this regex is still needed, I think. To check if user already written .domain.com. The rest is just parsing a string

Comment: I tried with that but as far as I can tell that code only validates the hostname in the format something.domain.tld. If I enter something.abc.com nothing happens. Maybe I got it wrong...

Comment: @BogdanStoica, yes it is only validation. So you want to parse string after it didn't go through validation? You can't change your string with regex, of course